# django modifying database object

Tags: python, django, templates, models

I am working on an attendance management system. I want to modify attendance of students.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    #attendance = models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)
    attendance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name


class Section(models.Model):
    section_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_name


class Student(models.Model):
    rollno = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rollno) + self.name
```

Here is my template. (Student.html)

```
{% for i in data %}  
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ i.rollno }}</td>
                    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
                    <td> <button class='btn btn-danger' id='{{i.rollno}}' on click = "{{ i.section.subject.get(subject_name='java').attendance)|add:1 }}"> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting error in using .get() method in template. I want to add (+1) attendance on a button click.

Comment: But that is not at all a thing you can do in the template, even leaving aside the syntax issues. Things like this must be done in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please help me. What should pass to the view as argument and how? I am new to django. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest to go through [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/). You will learn Django MVC concepts and able to achieve what you asked easily. The below code will help you get started.

**views.py**

```
def increment_attendance(request, subject_id):
  """Increment Attendance for a Subject"""

    subject = Subject.objects.get(id=subject_id)
    # check if record exists
    if not subject:
        raise Http404("Invalid subject_id")

    # can also use only get_object_or_404(Subject, pk=subject_id)

    # increment attendance
    subject.attendance += 1
    # save / commit to database
    subject.save()

    # redirec to 'some' page or previous page?
    return redirect('top')
```

**add this path to your urls.py**

```
  path('subject/<int:day>/increment_attendance', views.increment_attendance, name='increment_attendance')
```

**template**

```
  <a class="btn btn-danger" id="{{i.rollno}}" href="{% url 'increment_attendance' subject_id=subject_id" %}"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zekoi. Will you please comment on my models.py. This is my first project and I am not sure about the database I've made.